# How to install PIXEL on Ubuntu Server (64bit)

Tags: raspbian, ubuntu, pixel, 64-bit

I got a Raspberry PI 4 running 64bit Ubuntu Server. Now I have a bash prompt want a desktop environment. Hopefully, the PIXEL desktop to minimize differences from stock Raspbian.

A quick google turned up no obvious "apt install <>" suggestions.

Which packages can I install (or recompile) to get the Pixel desktop running?

Thanks in advance,

steve

Comment: There's no such thing as PIXEL. Google sent a cease and desist notice to the RPF folks and they renamed it.

Comment: Given the "distracted idiot" legal test (i'm the idiot) I think Google has a cause of action. Can you say what RPF changed the name TO?

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspberry-pi-desktop/ DebIan with Raspberry Pi Desktop. Current version is based on 32-bit DebIan Buster.

Answer (score 1):

The Raspberry PIXEL is a 32 bit window desktop manager. We have to wait for a 64 bit version. Until then you can try LXDE or Enlightenment 64 bit window managers supported by Ubuntu OS.

Comment: Current DebIan with Raspberry Pi desktop is 32-bit so that it is compatible with ancient hardware. I'd doubt it would go to 64-bit until DebIan Bullseye emerges as a stable [sic] version in a couple of year's time.